# Unusual behaviour of Array.prototype.fill inside Array.prototype.map

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

I have the following function:

```
const arrayOfStrings = n => new Array(n)
    .fill(new Array(2 * n - 1).fill(' '))
    .map((e, i) => e
        .fill(i, i, e.length - i)
            .join(''));
```

I expect when invoked like this `arrayOfStrings(3)`, I expect it to return the following:

```
[
    '00000',
    ' 111 ',
    '  2  '
]
```

However it doesn't, instead it returns this:

```
[
    '00000',
    '01110',
    '01210'
]
```

Or if I remove the `.join('')` from within the map and return `e` still as an array it returns this:

```
[
    [0,1,2,1,0],
    [0,1,2,1,0],
    [0,1,2,1,0]
]
```

What I believe is going on:

- `fill` called inside `map` is running on every child array element in the mapped parent array on each iteration.
- When `join` is present the the target child array (`e`) is returned as a string from each iteration, leaving one fewer arrays for the `fill` to be called on on the next iteration of `map`.
- When `join` is absent the all three `e` elements remain arrays and `fill` is run on every child array on every iteration.

**The Question**

I'm not concerned particularly with *how* to get my desired outcome. What I want to know is *why* calling `fill` inside `map` behaves in this way?

Thanks

Comment: It's because in `.fill(new Array(2 * n - 1).fill(' '))` you're creating a **single** array filled with spaces and putting a reference to it in every slot in your outer array. So in the `map`, you first fill the entire array with `0`, then fill a subset of it with `1`, and then fill a smaller subset of it with `2`. You need *different* arrays.

Comment: One common way is to use `Array.from`'s callback: `Array.from({length: n}, e => new Array(...))`. FWIW: http://jsbin.com/yewizuyuda/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Ahh thank you! I understand now, so `fill` only evaluates the first argument once and that's why it's all the same array. Cheers!